# details about the ports ( like in xammp port 80,) what are these ports?

Tags: server, xampp, port

I want to know if they are virtual, or real; something similar?
Can i increase them{if they are virtual} are they task specific?
Any thing will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux/Unix, they are defined in the file `/etc/services`. 80 is the common one for http. If you want an alternative web server, it's common to use numbers like 8000 or 8080.